# Is proxy password encrypted or hashed?

Tags: chocolatey

Proxy settings page states that with explicit settings a password gets encrypted:

```
choco config set proxyPassword <passwordThatGetsEncryptedInFile> # optional
```

https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/Proxy-Settings-for-Chocolatey#explicit-proxy-settings

Being precise, is it really encrypted or is it hashed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password is encrypted.

You can see that in action here:

https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/blob/4944318adfff2ea3fe910b4274f87bb3cf57e736/src/chocolatey/infrastructure.app/builders/ConfigurationBuilder.cs#L379

With the implementation being here:

https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/blob/19cdf4b0da51fcb5e12d9b616971e605a3ff7c9a/src/chocolatey/infrastructure.app/nuget/NugetEncryptionUtility.cs#L25

Comment: Thanks a lot, I noticed CryptoHashProvider over here https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/tree/master/src/chocolatey/infrastructure/cryptography
and was wondering how it could work. But yeah - having only a hash of password couldn't allow you to log in.